# FileWritingMessageHandler - adding timestamp suffix to file

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have an issue on adding timestamp suffixes to files using spring integration.

Here is my FileWritingMessageHandler bean :

```
 public FileWritingMessageHandler getFileWritingMessageHandler(String directory) {
    FileWritingMessageHandler handler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File(directory));
    handler.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.REPLACE);
    handler.setExpectReply(false);
    handler.setDeleteSourceFiles(true);
    return handler;
}
```

I tried with `handler.setTemporaryFileSuffix(getCurrentTimeStamp());` but it does nothing

I tried also with a DefaultFileNameGenerator :

```
    DefaultFileNameGenerator suffixFileNameGenerator = new DefaultFileNameGenerator();
    suffixFileNameGenerator.setHeaderName("id");
    suffixFileNameGenerator.setExpression("payload.name + '"+ getCurrentTimeStamp()+"'");
    handler.setFileNameGenerator(suffixFileNameGenerator);
```

A timestamp is added but it's the same for all files. They are processed at different times so I would like to append that time to the file name.
How can I achieve that ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the time once and adding it as a literal to the expression.

You need to get the timestamp at runtime instead of bean initialization time; use the `T` operator to invoke a static method:

```java
suffixFileNameGenerator.setExpression("payload.name + T(System).currentTimeMillis()");
```